# Comparing strings that contain roman numerals and numbers

Tags: sql, comparison

How do you compare a string that has either a roman or numeral in it, using SQL. ie. 
compare "Hello World 3" to "Hello World III" How can I confirm that they are similar using SQL? Do I need to convert the number first then compare?

Comment: Will the roman numerals / numbers always occur at the end? If so, then you can use the substring function to strip that part and convert it into roman numeral/number, and then compare.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?